# best way for pass very big object between two pages with routing

Tags: angular, routes

I want to pass big object between two pages .
project hangs(chunk error) when using of queryparam for routing big object.
What is the best way for pass big object between two pages with routing ?

Comment: I think best way to share date one component to other is use service

Comment: Maybe an implementation of redux with ngrx should work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f97ICOaekNU but the best way I think is by using __deep linking__

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataService to share data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {
  public data: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  set(property, data) {
    this.data[property] = data;
  }

  get(property) {
    return this.data[property];
  }
}
```